# virsh (xen) not listing dom0 nor domU

Tags: xen, virsh

I have **Xen 4.4.2** installed on Ubuntu. 
`xl list` shows *Dom0* and all *DomU* but `virsh -c xen:/// list --all` doesn't return anything.

`virsh version` returns

```
Compiled against library: libvirt 1.2.2
Using library: libvirt 1.2.2
Using API: Xen 1.2.2
Running hypervisor: Xen 4.4.0
```

Can't figure out why `virsh list --all` returns empty response.

How to fix this? Any suggestion is welcome. 
Thanks

**EDIT:**
okay, seems that I can't see domains created with `xl`. What I did is `virsh -c xen:/// domxml-from-native xen-xm domU_name.cfg` and then started domain again using `virsh create` with previously generated `xml`. 
Is there a way to convert somehow all of *domUs* so that `virsh` can list them/control them?